# Android always throw ClassCastException

Tags: android, ant

I built my android project from command line and compile using `ant debug install`. But after i import a external project called [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) to my project, my project becomes abnormal when running. Sometimes after i add a new id or delete a id in xml layout file, and my compile goes well but when the app starting to run, it throws a `ClassCastException`.
When it happens i can only use `ant clean && ant debug install` to fix it. But recompile a hole project costs double time, i don't wish to compile a project for one minute or more. So can i do some trick to make this error won't happen again?

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zhangdan.preferential/com.zhangdan.preferential.RecommendActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at com.zhangdan.preferential.RecommendActivity.findViews(RecommendActivity.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at com.zhangdan.preferential.RecommendActivity.onCreate(RecommendActivity.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
E/AndroidRuntime(21226):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  380):
```

RecommendActivity.java:

```
 64     private void findViews() { 
 65         mFakeListView = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.refreshable_list); 
 66         mListView = mFakeListView.getRefreshableView(); 
 67     }
```

xml:

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  2 <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView 
  3     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  4     xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  5     android:id="@+id/refreshable_list"
  6     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  7     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  8     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
  9     android:fadingEdge="none"
 10     android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
 11     android:divider="@null"
 12     android:paddingTop="5dip"
 13     android:paddingBottom="5dip"
 14     android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
 15     ptr:ptrMode="both" />
```

Comment: Do you have any details like a stack trace on the ClassCastException? Also, what does import an external project to my project mean? Is it a library project, a few files, or a totally separate project?

Comment: It's a library project. The error is like “TextView can't cast to RelativeLayout". The project is linked in project.properties.

Comment: A stack trace would still help.

Comment: @ChuckNorris I update the stack trace.

Comment: What is on line 65 in `RecommendActivity.java`?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I am sure that there is a Exception in my code. Because this issue happens i can fix it by just clean my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it happens i can only use ant clean && ant debug install to fix it. But recompile a hole project costs double time, i don't wish to compile a project for one minute or more.

Running `ant clean debug install` may be incrementally faster than running those operations separately.

You can also try modifying your Ant script to delete the `R.class` files in your `bin/classes/`, rather than using the `clean` command. I haven't tried this beyond a quick test just now, because usually this isn't a problem with a reasonable-sized project and a decent development machine. However, the heart of Joe's answer is that the last-compiled `R.class` files are out of sync with the to-be-generated `R.java` files, and for whatever reason, Ant's dependency mechanism does not always pick this up. Deleting the `R.class` files yourself (e.g., `find bin/classes -name R.class | xargs rm` on Linux) allows you to avoid `clean` and having to rebuild everything that `clean` wipes out, yet it will force a fresh recompile of the `R.java` classes. And, in *very* light testing, this appears to work, insofar as the resulting built APK works. As the saying goes, your mileage may vary.

Note that if you are using Android library projects -- like Pull-to-Refresh, there will be multiple `R.class` files (one for your app, one per library).

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be happening is that whenever you add/delete a layout ID in your project, somehow the `ant debug install` command does not correctly rebuild all the affected code and causes an ID for another widget to be used in place of the correct value for `R.id.refreshable_list`, which in turn causes the ClassCastException when your app is started.

Here's my suggestions:

- Check that all your files/folders have valid dates (maybe any of them are dated in the future?)
- Update your build tools to the latest versions (Android SDK, ant, and so on).
- What IDE are you using? Check to see if it has automatic build enabled which might somehow interfere with your command line build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i only develop under command line. and i have doubt the date of files is in the future, so i touch every file but without luck. i just wonder if others have the same problem, it slows my development speed quite a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes resource's errors can not seen. You should be sure that there isnt any error in your xmls. (com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView is right package?)

After you can try

1) delete your R Class
2) Clean project
3) fix project properties
4) rebuild.